# Boost::MPL Vector and For_Each: how to print avector as a tuple?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

So imagine we had a mpl::vector we want to print (cout for example) it as such string: `int, string, char`. How to do such thing with boost::mpl?

Answer (score 3):

Make a functor and call boost::for_each:

```
struct print_class_name {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T t ) const {
       std::cout << typeid(t).name() << " ";
    }
};

boost::mpl::for_each< Sequence >(print_class_name());
```

Comment: ...ups.. I meant print into #define in orderto get it as one preprocessor visiable string.